# ASP.net core MVC Partial view not unloading JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I am trying to call a client side function on unload to stop a connection to a signalR . The page that I am navigating to is a Partial View. When the partial view loads, a JS file loads that connects to the signalR hub and outputs the connectionID to the console. I would like for the connection to be broken when the user leaves the page, and re-established when they open it again. The GIF below shows going from the Home view, to the SSO partial view where the SignalR hub is connected. You can see when you leave and come back the connection is still alive, which is why I get the error that it can't connect again. I'd expect the alert to be called that I've left the page.

[image: behavior example]

I have added the following to my JS file, however the code never runs:

```
$(window).on("unload", function () {
    //stop the connection here
    alert("Goodbye!");
});
```

Is something like this possible when using partial views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making the hub site wide, which seems to be better practice anyway.